# Run test cases with Device emulators in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer, ts-jest, jest-puppeteer

I have 10 test cases in jest (Note: all tests are in `.test.ts` extension, for eg: `frontPageTest.test.ts`). I want to run the 10 test cases in Desktop view first, then the 10 test cases should run in mobile view. How to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.